# How do that in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I do this in SQL Server?

I have a table like this:

table1

```
userid    datetime             date         inoutmode 
-----------------------------------------------------    
123      2018-02-02 14:11:14   2018-02-02      0  
123      2018-02-02 18:52:44   2018-02-02      1 
123      2018-02-05 09:10:07   2018-02-05      0
```

---

```
0 = in 
1 = out
```

How can I put it in one row by date like this:

```
userid    date          intime    inmod   outtime   outmod  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
123       2018-02-02    14:11:14    0     18:52:44    1  
123       2018-02-05    09:10:07    0     (null) or 00:00:00  (null) or (9)
```

Comment: Do you expect the row to automatically `INSERT` when you `INSERT` into table1?  Or are you going to manually `INSERT INTO` table2 from querying table1?  Or is table2 a query result?

Comment: Per user and date you are showing a maximum of two rows, one for inoutmode 0, one for inoutmode 1. Is this guaranteed to be so or can there be more? If more, what to do? Get the earliest time or the latest one?

Comment: On a sidenote: You shouldn't store the date redundantly. The date is already included in the datetime column, so remove the date column in order to normalize the table and avoid future problems with inconsistencies. Or is the date column a computed column?

Comment: @alz_mohd Please update the title of your question. The title “How do that in SQL Server” is not helpful at all to any future visitor, ever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(userid INT, [datetime] datetime, [date] date, inoutmode INT)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(123, '2018-02-02 14:11:14', '2018-02-02', 0 ), 
(123, '2018-02-02 18:52:44', '2018-02-02', 1 ),
(123, '2018-02-05 09:10:07', '2018-02-05', 0 )

select 
    userid,
    [date],
    isnull( cast( min( case when inoutmode = 0 then [datetime] end ) as time ), '00:00:00') intime,   
    isnull( min( case when inoutmode = 0 then inoutmode end ) , 0 ) inmod, 
    isnull( cast( max( case when inoutmode = 1 then [datetime] end ) as time ), '00:00:00') outtime,
    isnull( max( case when inoutmode = 1 then inoutmode end ) , 9 ) outmod 
from @table1
group by
    userid, [date]
```

Result:

```
userid      date       intime   inmod       outtime  outmod
----------- ---------- -------- ----------- -------- -----------
123         2018-02-02 14:11:14 0           18:52:44 1
123         2018-02-05 09:10:07 0           00:00:00 9
```

Comment: hi all  thank for answer  table1 insert data from fingerdevice automatic Attendance employee if i want to make report for employee who came or Absence and insert result into another table how do that ?

Comment: You can add `INSERT INTO` above select query like `INSERT INTO table2( col1,col2,...) SELECT ... FROM table1`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input you can achieve that with the following:

```
;WITH Table1
    AS (
        SELECT 123 userid
            ,CAST('2018-02-02 14:11:14' AS DATETIME) [datetime]
            ,CAST('2018-02-02' AS DATE) [date]
            ,0 inoutmode

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 123 userid
            ,CAST('2018-02-02 18:52:44' AS DATETIME) [datetime]
            ,CAST('2018-02-02' AS DATE) [date]
            ,1 inoutmode

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 123 userid
            ,CAST('2018-02-05 09:10:07' AS DATETIME) [datetime]
            ,CAST('2018-02-05' AS DATE) [date]
            ,0 inoutmode
        )
SELECT [in].userid
    ,[in].[date]
    ,intime = CONVERT(TIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [in].[datetime], 108))
    ,inmod = [in].inoutmode
    ,outtime = ISNULL(CONVERT(TIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [out].[datetime], 108)), '00:00:00')
    ,outmod = ISNULL([out].inoutmode, 9)
FROM Table1 [in]
LEFT JOIN Table1 [out] ON [in].userid = [out].userid
    AND [in].DATETIME < [out].DATETIME
    AND [out].inoutmode = 1
WHERE [in].inoutmode = 0
```